# Angularjs Directive binding to inner content not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a simple feature toggle directive that needs to do a check and render content if that check succeeds. I don't want a new child scope (so I'm trying not to transclude) and I want the directive to be replaced by it's content. When I have model bindings in the html inside the directive then it loses it's binding.

The first checkbox below is the example ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLQafXMvcCqAOwhMsfE0?p=preview)). normalChecked stays bound and toggleChecked does not. Can anyone tell me how I am supposed to do this with an angularjs directive?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('playground',[]);
var ToggleDirective = ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr){
            // timeout replicates http request
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log("here");
                $element.replaceWith($element.children());
            }, 100);
        }
    };
}];
app.directive('toggle', ToggleDirective);
</script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="playground" ng-init="vm={toggleChecked:true, normalChecked:true};">
    <toggle>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.toggleChecked">
    </toggle><br/>
    toggleChecked value = {{vm.toggleChecked}}<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.normalChecked"><br>
    normalChecked value = {{vm.normalChecked}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
The actual directive code calls an http service to see if the user has access to a feature and does the above code to remove the toggle element and replace it with it's contents if they do have access. If they do not have access it removes the element from the dom.

Comment: Why are you replacing the element inside the `$timeout` and not during, say, the compile phase?

Comment: My code actually passes a service in that does an $http request to see if the user has access based on an attribute of the element. eg <toggle feature="foo">the code you really want in the dom</toggle> I want the content to show if they have access to feature foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can´t see why you don´t want to transclude, your example does not show us the kind o "check" you want to do neither.

So here is how you can achieve it using `transclude` and `replace`, that will leave you with an extra wrapping `div`, and you can add a `ng-show` on it to display the content or not, based on your check:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DaThyPHqtWlKrdKDf7ei?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('playground',[]);
var ToggleDirective = ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude ng-show="showContent"></div>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr){
          $scope.showContent = true; // do your check here
        }
    };
}];
app.directive('toggle', ToggleDirective);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right about the check but I didn't think that was important to the question other than the timeout simulation. The extra element can cause issues when using this around an li in an ul which is my first use case. Also, transclude adds an extra child scope which could break an app that's using this.

Comment: Well, I´m having problems understanding the usefulness of this directive then... lol

Comment: We are using it for feature toggles. I'm leaving out the part that goes to the web server to see if the current user has access to something then it replaces the directive with the inner content or removes the element if they don't have access. Our menu is a list with li's, so I can't wrap those in divs. Do you think there's a better way to show and hide things on the screen without adding new elements and scopes?

Comment: in that case you could use an attribute directive, that directive can receive a parameter indicating which permission it needs to check, then your directive should use a service to verify the permission on the server, when you receive the response, either show or hide the element. Keep in mind that to make it really secure, your server should return only the html (template) that the user has access, so you keep your security check entirely on the server.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it works good enough. I restrict the directive to attribute only and if the web service returns false then I do $element.remove(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the below code it will work.

```
//$element.replaceWith($element.children());
```

Because of this statement element loosing the scope.

I Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: I edited the question to give more details, but without that line then there's no need for the directive at all. I want the directive to replace itself with the contents if a user has access to a feature that is an attribute of toggle.